# How do I add a React form data to a Firebase real-time database?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am an new to reactjs. I am using `fireadmin dynamic admin panel` purchased version,in this panel i have created a page which contain a form.Now i wanted to save that form value to my firebase database.This admin panel has functionality to add data using schema file.But i wanted to add data from front end.I have followed the tutorial [video tutorial](http://fireadmin.mobidonia.com/videos.php). If u have any guidance please let me know.it also gives me error firebase is not function.

my function

```
 import Config from   '../config/app';    
 import DbConfig from   '../config/database';
    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({value: event.target.value});
    }


addMessage(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // <- prevent form submit from reloading the page
    /* Send the message to Firebase */
   DbConfig.database().ref('billing').push(this.inputEl.value,this.inputEm.value);

    this.inputEl.value = ''; // <- clear the input
    this.inputEm.value = ''; 
  }

          render() {
        return (
                <div className="content">
                <NavBar></NavBar>
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-10">
                <div className="card">
                    <form onSubmit={this.addMessage.bind(this)}>
      <input type="text" ref={ el => this.inputEl = el }/>
      <input type="text" ref={ em => this.inputEm = em }/>
      <input type="submit"/>

    </form>
            </div>

          </div>
                </div>
        )
      }
```

database.js

```
 import * as firebase from 'firebase';
require("firebase/firestore");
import Config from './app';

var FbApp = firebase.initializeApp(Config.firebaseConfig);
module.exports = FbApp; //this doesnt have to be database only
```

app.js

```
  //FireBase
     exports.firebaseConfig = {
         apiKey: "AIzaSyDsPufr5Dhusqal0bB8VDD9N6yv9u0Lo1E",
         authDomain: "tester-8e38d.firebaseapp.com",
         databaseURL: "https://tester-8e38d.firebaseio.com",
         projectId: "tester-8e38d",
         storageBucket: "tester-8e38d.appspot.com",
         messagingSenderId: "490493205074"
     };
```

Comment: have you checked that, firebase SDK is included in your project? https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup

Comment: yes there is sdk included its perfectly working with firebase but i wanted to save my inputed data to firebase.

Comment: How do you know that it is working? Is there some way to demonstrate this? You need to make sure you are exporting the database method from where you setup teh sdk and then import it where you want to use it.

Comment: now see my sdk code

Comment: Thank you. So if everything is connected correctly then you need to replace the `module.exports = FbApp;` with `export const rtdb = firebase.database()` in your database.js file. This will allow you to `import {rtdb} from '../path to database.js file` in your file where the react code is. Which will let you replace  `this.firebaseRef.push(NewTodo);` with `rtdb.ref().push(newTodo)` and you can remove `this.firebaseRef = new firebase('https://society-182906.firebaseio.com/docuemts/');` entirely. Give that a shot and let me knwo what error you get if it doesn't work.

Comment: ok i am trying this and let u know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fianlly i have found my solution and here is what i have done to resolved my issue. Thanks `@Josh Pittman` for `your guidance` without it i cant not make it out works.

```
  import Config from   '../config/app';
    import DbConfig from   '../config/database';  
     addMessage(e){
            e.preventDefault(); // <- prevent form submit from reloading the page
            /* Send the message to Firebase */
            var userInfo = {
                billing_name : this.pnm.value,
                billing_flat : this.fno.value,
              }; //user info
            DbConfig.database().ref('billing').push(userInfo);

            this.pnm.value = ''; // <- clear the input
            this.fno.value = ''; 
          }
     render() {
        return (
                <div className="content">
                <NavBar></NavBar>
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-12">
                <form onSubmit={this.addMessage.bind(this)}>
              <input type="text" ref={ el => this.inputEl = el }/>
              <input type="text" ref={ em => this.inputEm = em }/>
              <input type="submit"/>

            </form>
            </div>

          </div>
    </div>
        )
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

If the `this.handleChange` in your `.form-control` the input element is saving the input value to the state, then you need to save that state value to firebase on form submit. Use react dev tools to make sure what you want is being saved to state, or show us the `handleChange` method so we can see.

At the moment you are pulling from firebase on in your `handleAdd` method. Remove all the `this.rootRef.once...` code, that's for reading data. You want to write data.

Instead, first make sure you have your database function handy. It is unclear from your response above where you have written `let database = firebase.database();`. If it's in the same file as the code you have shown then replace `this.rootRef.push(NewTodo)` with `database.ref().push(NewTodo)` in your `handleAdd` method.

If `let database = firebase.database();` is not in the same file then you will need to export the database reference you just created and then import it at the top of the file you want to use it in. If the error you are getting is `database is not a function` then this is most likely the problem. Where are you setting up the SDK? If you explain this it will be easier to help you. I explain the basic of setup react and firebase in a post here https://joshpitzalis.svbtle.com/setup, it's for firestore database but its basically the same approach for the real-time database.

Another point of confusion is where the `text` parameter in `handleAdd(text)` is coming from. It is also unclear where you're using the `handleAdd` method. You seem to be using `this.handleSubmitFirebase` on form submit and `this.handleChange` on input change but you haven't shown us the code for either method so it's really confusing. Make sure the  `handleAdd(text)` is connected to the UI somehow, I'd use it on form submit.

Comment: thanx for explanation i will update my question accordingly.

Comment: You still need to show us where you setup the sdk and what you are importing into the file you have shown us. I believe the problem is still that you have not initialised teh database method on firebase. Please refer to teh /setup link I posted above to see what I mean or refer to the docs here https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start

Comment: hey i have tried one solution but by that way i can save only single input values. can u please guide me how to save multiple input values?

Comment: If you want to push multiple values to the same point in your database then push an array or an object instead of a single value. This is a separate question though, if you are having trouble please post a separate question on stack to make it easier for other people to find the answer. Also, please make sure your question hasn't already been asked and answered and do have a look at the docs before you ask https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write

Answer (score 1):

First of all add firebase package from npm.

```
-> config/fire contains firebase information
```

Student.js

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import fire from './config/fire';
import Home from './Home';
class Student extends Component {
constructor() {
super()
this.state = {
    email: '',
    password: ''}
this.Change = this.Change.bind(this);
this.press = this.press.bind(this);
}
Change(e) {
    this.setState({
        [e.target.name]: e.target.type === 'number' ? parseInt(e.target.value) : e.target.value,
    });
}
press(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var nmbr = this.state.userId + 1
    if (e.target.innerText === "Signin") {
        this.setState({
            redirect: true,
            userId: nmbr
        }, () => {
            fire.database().ref("Students/").child("userdata").set({
                password: this.state.password,
                email: this.state.email,
            }).then((data) => {
                //success callback
                console.log('data ', data)
            }).catch((error) => {
                //error callback
                console.log('error ', error)
            })
        })
    }
}
render() {
return (
    <form className="center
    <h1 style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>{this.props.value} </h1>
        <div className="col-md-4 center boundary">
                <div className="form-row center">
                    <div className="form-group col-md-11 center Text-center" >
                        <label htmlFor="inputEmail">Your Email</label>
                        <input type="email" onChange={this.Change} className="form-control" id="inputEmail" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="form-row center">
                    <div className="form-group col-md-11 center Text-center">
                        <label htmlFor="inputPassword">Set Password</label>
                        <input type="password" onChange={this.Change} className="form-control" id="inputPassword" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="form-row center">
                    <div className="form-group col-md-5 center text-center">
                        <button type="submit" onClick={this.press} className="btn btn-primary ">Signin</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    );
  }
}
export default Student;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all add firebase package from npm.

> npm install firebase --save

Then, import firebase instance

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

let database = firebase.database();
database().ref('/users').once('value')
 .then(function (snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.val())
});
```

Comment: database is not function Error

Comment: Have you import firebase properly?

Comment: yes firebase is working properly and already imported.but your solution got me this erro